# Fedora Thunderbird language

Tags: fedora, locale, thunderbird, language

```
----------------------------- 
OS: Fedora release 30 (Thirty) x86_64 
Host: Latitude 5580 
Kernel: 5.1.8-300.fc30.x86_64 
Uptime: 6 hours, 52 mins 
Shell: zsh 5.7.1 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: KDE 
WM: KWin 
Theme: Breeze [KDE], Adwaita [GTK2], Default [GTK3] 
Icons: breeze [KDE], Adwaita [GTK2], breeze [GTK3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: Intel i5-6440HQ (4) @ 3.500GHz 
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530 
Memory: 3936MiB / 7594MiB
```

I am located in Switzerland but my locales configuration is

```
> $ localectl status                                                                       
   System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: fr
      X11 Layout: fr
```

I just installed thunderbird and it appears in French whereas all my system is in English.

Maybe I need to configure mirrors with whom I am downloading my software

Answer (score 0):

I think `LC_CTYPE` has to be set to `en_US.UTF-8` in your case.
You see this setting with `locale`.